# SMOreg taking too much time in java code

Tags: java, weka

I am using SMOreg(SVM regression) from weka in my java code. It is taking  more than 30 min at buildClassifier() method. When I ran same inputs through weka gui toolbox it is hardly taking 2 mins. Here is part of my code.

```
Instances trainD = DataSource.read(trin_file);
trainD.setClassIndex(trainD.numAttributes()-1);
SMOreg predict = new SMOreg();
predict.buildClassifier(trainD);
```

Is there any specific reason to take longer time in java-code for same task?

Comment: The Weka GUI toolbox is also Java. What does the output of the GUI toolbox say? Can you get the same information from your code? That would be a start.

Comment: Are you sure that you pass the same options to the classifier? Have you check if you have read properly your data?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not passing all of the same options. Also, make sure you're allocating the same amount of memory for running the GUI and running your native java code.

In general, regression takes a while. As one example, I had an experiment that took about 2 hours to run using SMO/SVM (classification). When I changed the class attribute to be continuous, and ran SMOreg, it took over a day to run.